# How to copy new created file from multiple directory into single directory uisng ssis or cmd?

Tags: cmd, ssis

I have multiple folders in a single directory and each folder(folder name as per Siteid) contains the `.orig` file. so I want to copy the latest file created "`.orig`" file from multiple directories into a single directory.
The file received from ftp  in each directory on a weekly basis
Filename format

```
:PSAN{SiteId}_20190312_TO_20190318_AT_201903191600.txt
```

I tried to copy a file using windows command

```
for /R "source" %f in (*.orig) do copy %f "destination"
```

using this command I able to copy an all .orig file from multiple folders into a single folder but it fetches all file.

can we do modification in command to fetch the latest file?
How to perform this task using an SSIS package or using cmd.

Answer (score 0):

Create two package variables called InputFileNameWithPath and OutputFolderPath. The Former will be dynamically set in the package. The former should be hardcoded to your destination folder name.

Create a ForEachLoop enumerator of type File Enumerator. Set the path to the root folder and select the check box for traverse sub-folders. You may want to add an expression for the FileMask and set it to `*.orig` that way only the .orig files are moved (assuming there are other files in the directory that you do not want to move) Assign the fully qualified path to the package variable InputFileName.

Then add a System File Task into the ForEachLoop enumerator and have it move the file. from the InputFileNameWithPath to the OutputFolderPath.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Script Task to achieve that, you can simply store the folders within an array, loop over these folders get the latest file created and copy it to the destination directory (you can achieve this without SSIS), as example:

```
using System.Linq;

string[] sourcefolders = new string[] { @"C:\New Folder1", @"C:\New Folder2" };
string destinationfolder = @"D:\Destination";

foreach (string srcFolder in sourcefolders)
{

    string latestfile = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(srcFolder, "*.orig").OrderByDescending(x => System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(x)).FirstOrDefault();

    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(latestfile))
    {

        System.IO.File.Copy(latestfile, System.IO.Path.Combine(destinationfolder, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(latestfile)));

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

An example C# Script Task for this is below.  This uses SSIS variables for the source and destination folders, and make sure to add these in the `ReadOnlyVariables` field if that's how you're storing them.  Be sure that you have the references listed below as well.  As noted below, if a file with the same name exists it will be overwritten to avoid such an error, however I'd recommend confirming that this meets your requirements.  The third parameter of `File.Copy` controls this, and can be omitted as it's not a required parameter.

```
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;


string sourceFolder = Dts.Variables["User::SourceDirectory"].Value.ToString();
string destinationFolder = Dts.Variables["User::DestinationDirectory"].Value.ToString();

Dictionary<string, string> files = new Dictionary<string, string>();
DirectoryInfo sourceDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(sourceFolder);

foreach (DirectoryInfo di in sourceDirectoryInfo.EnumerateDirectories())
{
    //get most recently created .orig file
    FileInfo fi = di.EnumerateFiles().Where(e => e.Extension == ".orig")
                        .OrderByDescending(f => f.CreationTime).First();
     //add the full file path (FullName) as the key
     //and the name only (Name) as the value
    files.Add(fi.FullName, fi.Name);
}

foreach (var v in files)
{
   //copy using key (full path) to destination folder 
   //by combining destination folder path with the file name
   //true- overwrite file if file by same name exists
    File.Copy(v.Key, destinationFolder + v.Value, true);
}
```